# Build Two Half Pyramids in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm in an introduction to C++ course, and my assignment is to build two half pyramids with height input by the user, with two spaces in between. They should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6GtL.jpg). The user can only input an integer between 1 and 23.

EDIT: This is the answer my teacher wanted - she initially asked for us to use arrays to make these, but later changed her mind to do the project with for loops instead.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int i,j,h;
cout << "Welcome to Mario. Please enter an integer between 1 and 23." << endl;
cin >> h;

for(i=0;i<h;i++)
    {
    for(j=h;j>0;j--)
    {
        if (i+1 >= j)
            cout << "#";
        else
            cout << " " ;
    }
    cout << "  " ;

    for (j=0;j<h;j++)
        {
        if (i>=j)
        cout << "#";
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

[The generated two half pyramids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6GtL.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the [Tour] and see [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a 2D array...
Although the code is not complete yet. The same pattern can be applied from 8-23..

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int height ;
    cout << "Please select height from 1 - 23" << endl;
    cin >> height;

    if (height == 1)
    {
        char array [1][13] =
        {
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ' }};


        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x ++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 13; y ++)
            {
                cout <<array[x][y] ;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (height == 2)
    {
        char array [2][13] =
        {
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*', ' ',' ',' ',' '}};

        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x ++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 13; y ++)
            {
                cout <<array[x][y] ;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    }

    else if (height == 3)
    {
        char array [3][13] =
        {
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*', ' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ', ' ','*','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*','*', ' ', ' '       }};

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x ++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 13; y ++)
            {
                cout <<array[x][y] ;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (height == 4)
    {
        char array [4][13] =
        {
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*', ' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ', ' ','*','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*','*', ' ', ' '       },
            {' ', '*','*','*','*', ' ',' ', '*','*','*','*',' ',' ' }};

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x ++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 13; y ++)
            {
                cout <<array[x][y] ;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }


    else if (height == 5)
    {
        char array [5][13] =
        {
            {' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*', ' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ', ' ','*','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*','*', ' ', ' '       },
            {' ', '*','*','*','*', ' ',' ', '*','*','*','*',' ',' ' },
            { '*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ', '*','*','*','*','*' }};

        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x ++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 13; y ++)
            {
                cout <<array[x][y] ;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

    }

    else if (height == 6)
    {
        char array [6][15] =
        {
            {' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
            { ' ',' ', ' ', ' ','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*', ' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
            {' ',' ', ' ','*','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*','*', ' ', ' ' ,' '      },
            {' ',' ', '*','*','*','*', ' ',' ', '*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ' },
            {' ', '*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ', '*','*','*','*','*',' ' },
            {'*', '*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ', '*','*','*','*','*','*' }};

        for (int x = 0; x < 6; x ++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 15; y ++)
            {
                cout <<array[x][y] ;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (height == 7)
    {
        char array [7][17] =
        {
            {' ',' ',' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '*', ' ',' ','*',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '  },
            { ' ',' ',' ', ' ', ' ','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*', ' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ' },
            {' ',' ',' ', ' ','*','*','*', ' ',' ',  '*','*','*', ' ', ' ' ,' ' ,' '      },
            {' ',' ',' ', '*','*','*','*', ' ',' ', '*','*','*','*',' ',' ',' ',' '  },
            {' ',' ', '*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ', '*','*','*','*','*',' ' ,' ' },
            {' ','*', '*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ', '*','*','*','*','*','*' ,' ' },
            {'*','*', '*','*','*','*','*',' ',' ', '*','*','*','*','*','*' ,'*' }};

        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x ++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 17; y ++)
            {
                cout <<array[x][y] ;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (height == 8)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 9)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 10)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 11)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 12)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 13)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 14)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 15)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 16)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 17)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 18)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 19)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 20)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 21)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 22)
    {

    }
    else if (height == 23)
    {

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this program. It works by printing one large triangle, and then replacing the middle column by 'space'. It uses a pair of for loops inside another for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, i, sp, k;
    cin >> n;
    n += 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (sp = 1; sp <= n - i; sp++) {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for (k = 0; k != 2 * i - 1; k++) {
            if (k == (2 * i - 1) / 2) {
                cout << "  ";
            }
            else cout << "#";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

}
```